# Cannot use 'user' resource in Chef

Tags: chef-infra

Just learning to use Chef and I cannot seem to do even basic user creation.

Here's the recipe:

```
user 'bob' do
  action :create
  password '$1$NSy4M315$KfqF7bX49YgJuhdJZPqbv1'
end
```

And the error:

```
sudo chef-solo -c recipes/bob.rb 
[2017-04-13T11:05:41-07:00] FATAL: Configuration error NoMethodError: undefined method `action' for nil:NilClass
[2017-04-13T11:05:41-07:00] FATAL:   /home/nicholas/dev/vagrant/current/akm/recipes/bob.rb:2:in `block in from_string'
[2017-04-13T11:05:41-07:00] FATAL:   /home/nicholas/dev/vagrant/current/akm/recipes/bob.rb:1:in `from_string'
[2017-04-13T11:05:41-07:00] FATAL: Aborting due to error in '/home/nicholas/dev/vagrant/current/akm/recipes/bob.rb'
```

I added `depends 'user'` to metadata.rb, but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-c` flag to chef-solo (and all Chef commands) sets the path to the config file. You are trying to run a recipe, not set up a Chef config file.

You probably want something like `chef-apply recipes/bob.rb` for one-off learning experiments or something like `chef-solo --option chef_repo_root=. -r recipe[cookbookname]` for more production-y usage.